How to remove key "com.apple.developer.associated-domains" from plist file using plutil
We're using plutil to manipulate plist files (such as Info.plist and Entitlements.plist) at build time. It works perfectly with all kind of keys when I run plutil -remove "key1". When I want to remove the key "com.apple.developer.associated-domains" using following command
plutil -remove "com.apple.developer.associated-domains"

it returns the following error:
No value to remove at key path com.apple.developer.associated-domains

The key is present, as you can see in the following Entitlements.plist file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:mycompany.com</string>
        <string>applinks:mycompany.com*</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>

